# Angular 6 Format date from datepicker in Reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, angular-formbuilder, mat-datepicker

I am trying to use Angular 6 with reactive forms and to format the date value getting from the datepickers which will be passed to the next stage.

In the example code where I use the reactive form to convert the date format, it was working when I first selected the date from datepicker. However, when I edit other input fields afterwards, the previous entered date value was back to Moment Object and only the last selected date was in the correct format.

Expected result (example):

```
{ users: [name: a, start: 2021/11/20, end: 2022/10/15]}
```

Actual Result:

```
{ users: [name: a, start:  Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: {…}, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, …}, end: 2022/10/15]}
```

TS code:

```
    userForm: FormGroup;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.createUserForm();
      }
    
      createUserForm() {
        this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          users: this.formBuilder.array([this.createEachUser()])
        });
      }
      createEachUser(): any {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
          name: this.formBuilder.control(null, [Validators.required]),
          start: this.formBuilder.control(null, [Validators.required]),
          end: this.formBuilder.control(null, [Validators.required]),
        });
      }
    
      convertDate(moment, startend, i) {
        const date = moment.value['_d'];                               // moment is Moment Object
        const newDate = new Date(date).toISOString().split('T')[0]; // ex: 2021/11/20
        this.userForm.value.users[i][startend] = newDate;
      }
    
      submit() {
        console.log(this.userForm.value)
      }
```

HTML:

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()" [formGroup]="userForm" novalidate>
  <div formArrayName="users" *ngFor="let user of userForm.controls.users?.value; let i = index;">
    <div class="col">
      <label class="label">Name:</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name" formControlName="name" required>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <label class="label">Start:</label>
      <input class="form-control" [matDatepicker]="startpicker" (click)="startpicker.open()" id="start" name="start" formControlName="start" (dateChange)="convertDate($event,'start', i)" required>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startpicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #startpicker></mat-datepicker>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <label class="label">End:</label>
      <input class="form-control" [matDatepicker]="endpicker" (click)="endpicker.open()" id="end" name="end" formControlName="end" (dateChange)="convertDate($event,'end', i)" required>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="endpicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #endpicker></mat-datepicker>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with formatting the date and this is what I came up with:( I dont use mat-datepicker)

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <br>
    <input formControlName="date" id="date" type="date" />
    <br>
     {{form.value.date | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd' }} 
</form>
```

.TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-date',
  templateUrl: './date.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date.component.scss']
})
export class DateComponent {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      date: ['']
    });
  }

}
```

to add validators:

```
date: ['',Validators.requiredTrue]
```

for different types of formatting of the Date look at this:  https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

to Format a Date in Code have a look at this API (doesnt suit the example but give u a hint):

```
datetimeVal: Date;
          
  this.formattedIsoTime = this.datetimeVal.toISOString();
  this.formattedLocaleTime = this.datetimeVal.toLocaleDateString() 
  this.formattedUTCTime =   this.datetimeVal.toUTCString();
```

Comment: Angular and Material UI won't include it as a component if it is not working.  A workaround is not recommended, rather, a solution.